# How can I pass fixed arguments using scipy minimize()?

Tags: python, scipy, minimize

How can I optimize two variables in a three variable function? My understanding was that I can include the last variable in the args parameter, but I cannot make this work. What am I doing wrong here? The idea is that I want to optimize x and y and that z is fixed.

```
> from scipy.optimize import minimize
> def f(x,y,z):return x**2 * y**2 - x*y*z*32 +10
> minimize(f,[1,2,3],args=[2])
TypeError: f() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea here is that the function that you want to minimize has to accept an array of parameters for minimization *and* optional arguments. So you have to assign manually input array to function parameters:

```
>>> def f(xs, z):
...     x, y = xs
...     return x**2 * y**2 - x*y*z*32 +10
... 
>>> minimize(f, [1,3], args=(2,))
   status: 2
  success: False
     njev: 18
     nfev: 84
 hess_inv: array([[ 0.02619011, -0.02104178],
       [-0.02104178,  0.02982305]])
      fun: -1014.0000000000002
        x: array([ 5.79312665,  5.52378745])
  message: 'Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.'
      jac: array([  3.05175781e-05,   1.52587891e-05])
      nit: 6
```